# How to render a 50x50 table in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**CODE:**

Here is some pseudocode of what I am trying to achieve:

```
class Board extends React.Component {
    render() {

        cells = for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            return <Cell />;
        }

        board = for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            return <tr>{cells}</tr>;
        }

        return (
            <table>
                {board}
            </table>
        );
    }
}
```

What is the right approach to create this square 250 cells array in React ?

```
class Cell extends React.Component {
    render() {

        return (
            <div className="cell"></div>
        );

    }   
}
```

---

**SITUATION:**

Trying to render a 50x50 Table in React.

Comment: That's because you're using +=! You're adding objects together and that converts them into what you see!

Comment: There's also the minor detail that `div` elements are not valid direct children of `tr` elements...

Comment: @AndrewLi I know ! I am looking for a solution :D I forgot how to render many elements  :/

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Correct, I had forgotten that rule :/ Strangely, no error appeared regarding that hmmm

Comment: @Coder1000 HTML doesn't give errors, it's just not valid by spec.

Comment: @AndrewLi I actually had this error pop out a few times before :D Anyway, can I please get some guidance here ?

Comment: looks like you should reread the use of *return* ...

Comment: @Jonasw Looks like you should reread the meaning of pseudocode :D (I did not precise it at first, I admit my question was badly formulated and I was rewriting it but had to answer to comments like yours)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're still thinking in markup, but React lets you work with *object*s. When you do `<div>x</div>` in JSX, you're *creating an object*. You were getting `"[object Object]"` because that's what you get when you apply `+` to an object that doesn't define `toString` in any special way (e.g., that's what the default `Object.prototype.toString` does).

Instead, build up an array of cells, and an array of rows, etc.; see comments:

```js
class Board extends React.Component {
    render() {
        // Build the rows in an array
        let rows = [];
        for (let y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
            // Build the cells in an array
            const cells = [];
            for (let x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
                cells.push(<Cell />);
            }
            // Put them in the row
            rows.push(<tr>{cells}</tr>);
        }
        // Return the table
        return <table><tbody>{rows}</tbody></table>;
    }
}

class Cell extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <td className="cell"></td>;
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Board />,
    document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
.cell {
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

(I reduced it to 10x10 just to fit easily, and also used `td` rather than `div` in `Cell`.)

---

That's the verbose version for clarity. Using `Array.from`, we can make `Board` look like this if we want:

```
const Board = _ =>
  <table>
    <tbody>
    {Array.from({length:10}, _ =>
        <tr>{Array.from({length:10}, _ => <Cell />)}</tr>
    )}
    </tbody>
  </table>
;
```

That uses a *stateless functional component* (a component that's just a function) and builds the rows via `Array.from`'s mapping function, within which we build the cells using `Array.from`'s mapping function again.

```js
const Board = _ =>
  <table>
    <tbody>
    {Array.from({length:10}, _ =>
        <tr>{Array.from({length:10}, _ => <Cell />)}</tr>
    )}
    </tbody>
  </table>
;

class Cell extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <td className="cell"></td>;
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Board />,
    document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
.cell {
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

To be uber-clear: I did *two* different, unrelated things there: 1) Using an SFC, and 2) Using `Array.from` and arrow functions. Here's the same thing not using an SFC:

```
class Board extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <table>
        <tbody>
        {Array.from({length:10}, _ =>
          <tr>{Array.from({length:10}, _ => <Cell />)}</tr>
        )}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}
```

```js
class Board extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <table>
        <tbody>
        {Array.from({length:10}, _ =>
          <tr>{Array.from({length:10}, _ => <Cell />)}</tr>
        )}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}

class Cell extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <td className="cell"></td>;
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Board />,
    document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
.cell {
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Coder1000: Glad that helped! I've just added an update if you want to look at using some even more advanced JavaScript features at some point. Enjoy. :-)

Comment: I read about stateless functional components 2 days ago, but I will admit I am not there yet :D Thx for the bonus !